# Enumeration with methods C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a small set of special elements (for this I used enumeration) and than overload operators on them (for example I want to add, subtract or compare them but not like regular integers).

I ended up creating a struct that holds one variable of that enumeration and defined all my operators there. Is there a better way to do this, because my program is getting full of similar names.

```
Enumeration ExampleEnum
{x,y,z};

struct ExampleStruct
{
ExampleEnum value;
//rest of code with operators
};
```

Comment: You can take a look at [bitflags](https://github.com/m-peko/bitflags) library

Comment: You can define your own operators for enum type, why do you need struct? https://wandbox.org/permlink/4jCMLo0Gw3vTWs70

Comment: should this be `enum ExampleEnum {x,y,z};` ?